# How do I prove that every chain has an upper bound?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $A$ be a non-empty set.

Let $X$ be the collection of bijections $f:U→V$ where $U,V$ are disjoint subsets of $A$.

Define the relation $≥$ as follows:
$$(f:U→V) ≥ (f′:U′→V′) \text{ iff } U′⊆ U \text{ and }V′⊆ V f|_{U′}=f′$$

How do I prove that for every chain in $X$ there is an upper bound in $X$?

I think I mostly know how, but it's a matter of how to write it:

Let $C$ be a chain. Consider: union of all the functions in chain $C$. The union of the $U$'s is a subset of $A$, similarly the union of $T$'s in $C$ is also a subset of $A$. The Union of functions I assume is just the union of all the pairs, and since every function is bijective then the union will be bijective.

How do I concisely and elegantly write this proof?

A specific problem I have is how to represent the chain? should it be like this:
$$C = \{f_\gamma:U_\gamma \to V_\gamma\ |\ \text{ for all }\gamma \in \Gamma\}$$

Comment: Rarely things are *truly* concise and elegant. You have to have something that does the ugly work for you. Either previous theorems and lemmata, or just ad-hoc claims inside the proof. Depending on what you already proved showing that the union of a chain is a bijection can be either very concise and elegant, or requiring verification of some tedious details.

Comment: I understand.. but  I was wondering if there is an elegant way one can demonstrate this without resorting to tedious and ugly proofs.

Comment: You cannot escape the need to prove that the union of a chain of bijections is a bijection. The definitions are very basic, and you just have to sit and verify them. Either in the proof, or before hand using various lemmas about when the union of functions is a function, when the union of injections is an injection, and when the union of surjections is a surjection. There is no escape from this.

Answer (score 3):

Let's write $X = \{f_\alpha: U_\alpha \to V_\alpha\}$ for notational purposes, and let $U = \bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$, $V = \bigcup_\alpha V_\alpha$ and $f = \bigcup_\alpha f_\alpha$

There are a couple of things that need checking:

1. $f$ is still a function:

This is because $f_\alpha \leq f_\beta$ implies $f_\beta|_{U_\alpha} = f_\alpha$: that is, if $x \in U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$ then (since $X$ is a chain) we have either $f_\alpha \leq f_\beta$ or vice-versa, and so $f_\alpha(x) = f_\beta|_{U_\alpha}(x) = f_\beta(x)$.

2. $f$ is still injective:

Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$. Then we can find some $U_\alpha$ that contains both $x$ and $y$ (again since $X$ is a chain), and so we get $f_\alpha(x) = f_\alpha(y)$, so $x = y$.

3. $f$ is still surjective:

If $v \in V$ then have $v \in V_\alpha$, for some $\alpha$, and so there is some $x \in U_\alpha$ with $f(x) = f_\alpha(x) = v$.

4. $U$ and $V$ are still disjoint:

If $x \in U \cap V$ then $x \in U_\alpha$ and $x \in V_\beta$. Since $X$ is a chain we have $U_\alpha \subseteq U_\beta$ (or vice-versa) so wlog $x \in U_\beta \cap V_\beta$, which is a contradiction.

Your question about 'how to represent the chain' is just a matter of preference - I think the above notation is pretty clear, but I'm sure there are other ways you could write it. Note that some people consider a chain to be e.g. $f_0 \leq f_1 \leq f_2 \leq \ldots$ (especially in computer science), but normally the more general definition of 'a totally ordered subset of a poset' is used.

Comment: How does your reasoning show that $f$ is still a function?

Comment: I'm checking that $f$ is well-defined: given $x \in U$, you can choose any $\alpha$ such that $x \in U_\alpha$ and define $f(x) = f_\alpha(x)$. The argument I give shows that it doesn't matter which $\alpha$ you choose.